# Azure data factory - multiple primary keys in source excel to be inserted in SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database, etl, azure-data-factory, primary-key, azure-mapping-data-flow

I am working on a pipeline where I am using Excel as the source. The data has a primary key let's say `Id`, which is repeating multiple times in the Excel.

Now, when I insert it into a SQL database, it fails with the error:

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.xyz'. The duplicate key value is XXXX.

How can I make take care of this scenario using mapping data flows in ADF?

I am using a mapping data flow here to take care of the different other transformations.

Example of such data, coming from the Excel source

ID  Name         PhoneNo
1   John Doe     11110000
1   John Doe     88881111
2   Harry Potter 88999000
2   Harry Potter 00001112
3   abc xyz      77771111

I need to take save the top 1 ID and Name (and there are more columns) in one table and Phone No and ID will be saved in another

Comment: Hi @user961, Can you provide a sample source and expected output? As the table has a primary key constraint on the Id column, you cannot insert duplicate values into the SQL table.

Comment: If the ID repeats multiple times then it cannot be a primary key; a Primary Key is, by definition, unique within the dataset. Perhaps your Primary Key candidate should be made up of a couple of columns (though these are difficult to work with), or perhaps your data set requires normalisation into several tables.

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT - added the sample data for your reference in the post itself. Thanks for your prompt responses.

Comment: What does "take care of this scenario" mean? Especially since your description does not make sense since "a primary key [...] which is repeating multiple times" cannot happen, as you were already told. Explain exactly what is given, what it the goal & where you are 1st stuck.. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. [mre]. PS Give a table in block code format or table format. Input tables to code should be initialization code. See the edit help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `aggregate` transformation to remove duplicate values from the source.

**Source**:

Add sample excel source with duplicate values in ID and Name columns.

[image]

**Aggregate transformation:**

Under the **group by** property, add the list of columns in which the duplicate rows are identified.

[image]

Under the **aggregates** property, add the aggregate column. Here, we are getting the first value of the Phone column from the duplicate rows.

Expression: `first(Phone)`

[image]

**Aggregate output:**

[image]

**Sink1:**

Add the aggregate output to sink1 to pass the ID, and Name columns to 1 table.

[image]

**Sink2:**

Add another sink after aggregate transformation to pass Id and phone to a different table.

[image]

Comment: This approach will miss the data for the second table. I need to save all values for the second table as well.